# Nuxt3 generate static list data, and also with ClientOnly funcationality for fetching extra statistical data in real time?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt3

1, I have a component cat-[catagory]-[page].vue, for different catagories products, driven by dynamic Nuxt route

2, In the cat-[catagory]-[page].vue component, I have another component productslist.vue

3, In the productslist.vue component:

a) bind data via the property products

const props = defineProps({
products: {
type: Object,
required: true,
}
});

b) based on the products property, trying to fetch extra statistical data via call backend API.

**All of those work fine in dev Nuxt model.**

**But after npm run generate: the basic products data was bind successfully, but the extra statistical data was NOT bind. I checked, found the related statistical data backend API was not called.**

What I expected is: the basic products data is generated as static data in html file, and the extra statistical data is fetched in browser in real time.

This should be a normal requirement for Nuxt static mechanism, but I didn't find out why it is not working.

Could you please give some help? Any comments are welcome.